# вынос стандартных методов в пользовательскую функцию (теория)

Tags: php

Новичок в php, но не в разработке в целом. На работе с наставником возник "спор".

По коду нужно проверить существование элемента массива.
Он говорит, что *правильнее* было бы в коде ниже вывести проверку в отдельную функцию `check`. И, в целом, привыкать к такому стилю.
Мне же непонятно, зачем выводить в отдельную функцию, которая возвращает `true/false` стандартный метод isset, который сам по себе возвращает `true/false`.
Моя позиция:

1. в функцию надо выносить код, который используется в скрипте минимум 2 раза. Если проверка хоть в 100 строк проводится единожды - нет смысла выносить ее в отдельную функцию.
2. превращать 1 строку кода в 3 (как в примере ниже) нецелесообразно.

```js
<?php

//first variant
if(isset($array['key'])){
    #code here;
};


//second variant;
if(check($array['key'])){
    #code here;
}

function check($el){
    return isset($el);
}
```

P.S. Своими утверждениями не претендую на истину, могу ошибаться. Хочется услышать ваши мнения.

Comment: В данном случае вы вообще оба не правы  Но коллега больше. Если кейс заключается ровно в том, что вы описали и нет никаких доп. условий, то он не прав чтобы выделять это в функцию, т.к.есть нативные методы и не прав выделять в функцию с бестолковым наименованием......вы же не правы потому, что наличие ключа проверяется на array_key_exists ))) а isset не сработает, если значение у key = null

Comment: теоретически check() может проверять не только isset(), но и null, пустую строку и другое.

Comment: @Jean-Claude вообще методы: check, validate должны выкидывать исключения, а проверки на bool: is, has и прочие. По моему мнению, это более корректно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то есть в том, что функции надо создавать, только если код дважды используется, а не то чтобы логически разделять функционал, тут он прав? )

Comment: @teran это тоже)

Comment: @teran чуйка вас подвела, код не пишется, в названии вопроса в скобочка написано (теория) это теоретический спор. Если мне нужно проверить больше ли единицы переменная, меньше или равна ей - нормально будет если я эти 3 проверки внутри функции вынесу в 3 отдельных функции? Я хочу проверить правильно ли я мыслю, а не утверждаю что я прав (это, кстати, тоже написано в моем вопросе)